# iPhone, playing a movie in landscape but return to portrait when movie is complete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Total Objective-C/XCode N00b here but I am attempting something, which I assume is simple.  I have an app that is written for the iPhone, I don't allow auto orientation and only have the main interface locked into portrait.  When the user plays a video in the app I would like to allow them to auto rotate the device from portrait and watch it in landscape (should they choose to do so, I don't want to force this).  Once the user presses "Done", I would like to force them back into portrait (even if they are holding the device in landscape) as the interface is only laid out in that orientation.

I've tried using the MPMoviePlayerController and MPMoviePlayerViewController and I am not sure which will give me the leverage/methods I need.  I am basically just looking to allow shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to return yes only when the MPMoviePlayerController view is visible.

Any help MUCH appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I used [this code exampl](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html)e and it worked perfectly. I think you'll have to set the orientation in the super class.